# How to prevent duplicate form submit in chrome during controller execution

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-ui

Form contains show PDF button which sends POST request.
This post request shows pdf file using `Content-disposition: inline` or `Content-disposition: attachment` http header.

In Chrome double click in this button causes exception in controller probably becauses request 
is executed two times concurrently.

How to prevent this so that double click in submit button executes request only once ?

Environment: ASP .NET MVC2 or Mono, jquery, jquery ui.

```
<form id="_form" method='post' target='_blank' action=''>
  .. form fields and other submit buttons
  <a href='#' id='_savepdf'>Show PDF</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#_savepdf').button();
    $('#_savepdf').click(function () { 
      $('#_form')[0].action= '/GetPDF'; 
      $('#_form')[0].submit(); 
     });
  });
</script>
```

**Update**

User may want to close pdf file and click or double click in this button again. 
Only concurrent controller execution from same users should disabled. If controller has completed, button can clicked again.

Comment: FYI, element IDs should be unique, so you should only ever have one `#_form` - making the `[0]` unnecessary

Comment: @adam I think he's using the [0] to use native methods

Comment: @adam: action and submit() are native method and property. #_form returs reference only to jquery properties and method. So [0] must used

Comment: Wow, hadn't realised you could do that - I'd always used `.get()`

Comment: @Adam: form can contain long texts. Length of GET url is limited and those texts cannot passed using GET. I upadeted question title and querstion stating that after request is completed button click should alloweed again.

Comment: @Andrus I was replying to the comment about the use of `[0]` to get native methods, which can also be done using `.get()` - in this context, nothing to do with AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the button after click so a user cannot click more than once.

```
$('#_savepdf').button().click(function () { 
   $(this).button({disabled: true});
   $('#_form')[0].action= '/GetPDF'; 
   $('#_form')[0].submit(); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This puts button in disabled state forever. Question describes that tab containing form remains open. User may close pdf and may want to click or double click to this button again. So disabling it forever cannot used.

Comment: Is your form being submitted by ajax?  Usually form submits will cause a page reload or redirect

Comment: No. As code shows this is POST request and Content-disposition is used to open separate tab or cause save file prompt. Maybe it is best to add some logic to mvc2 controller? Also I can change code to ajax if this is best way.

Comment: @Andrus here's a link to something you probably need to do

Comment: @Andrus woops thought I added the link http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx

Comment: Thank you. This does not work if cookies are disabled. Mabe it is better to add some tcheck to controller and terminate controller if other instance of this controller is already executed ?

Comment: @Andrus yeah I've been looking around and it seems even the [jQuery filedownloader](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) plugins require the server to write back a cookie to allow for detection when the file download completes.

Comment: Thank you. I tried jQuery filedownloader. If controller returns `Content-disposition: inline` no pdf is opened. How to open pdf in new tab if using this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#_savepdf').button();
    $('#_savepdf').click(function (e) {  // <---- Don't forget e
      e.preventDefault();    // <------ HERE
      $('#_form')[0].action= '/GetPDF'; 
      $('#_form')[0].submit(); 
     });
});
```

*Edit:* Having not read thoroughly enough through the question the first time, I missed the part about the double-click. To prevent a double-click from doing anything maybe try adding a data attribute to your link:

```
<a href='#' id='_savepdf' data-clicked='false'>Show PDF</a>
```

Then you can check and set it in your method:

```
$(function () {
    $('#_savepdf').button();
    $('#_savepdf').click(function () {
        var clickSent = $(this).data('clicked');

        if (clickSent == 'false') {
            $('#_form')[0].action= '/GetPDF'; 
            $('#_form')[0].submit(); 
        }
        $(this).data('clicked', 'true');
     });
});
```

This should allow the attribute to be set once you've clicked the link, and the second click should skip the submission logic.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but problem persists. Problably `e.preventDefault()` does not disable `submit()` call which occurs on second click.

Comment: @Andrus: Yah I misread the question. I've posted an update reflecting the actual question you've asked.

Comment: Thank you. This disables all remaining clicks. Tab containing form remains open. User may close pdf and may want to click or double click to this button again. So disabling it forever cannot used. Maybe it is possble to add some check to mvc2 controller to prevent double execution or other idea.

Comment: I updated question title and content stating that concurrent execution by same user should prevented during controller execution only